# How to move the scroll of a div on keydown of listbox contents

Tags: listbox

I am having a listbox with large contents. I have used a div outside the listbox (no fixed height and width set)with a fixed width and height sothat the div is having both horizontal and vertical scroll. The list box within the div does not have any scroll. The div will not scroll down when i use key down for the listbox inside it. I want to move the scroll of the div according to the listbox key down. Can any one give a solution for this

Comment: I gave a keydown for the listbox option but that event is not firing for that selector

Comment: like this $("#<%=lbCommcatFrom.ClientID%> option:selected").keydown(function(event){ 
               
                 $("#<%=dvLeft.ClientID%>").animate({
                    'scrollTop': 40 
                    }, 10);   
            });